# Is it possible to override virtual path resolution behavior in Visual Studio's Asp.Net source editor and designer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have some images that are bundled into an assembly as embedded resources and accessible via an implementation of VirtualPathProvider. I also have an Asp.Net website that references this assembly and, in a given aspx, I can say something like:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/virtualpath/image.png" />
```

Where *virtualpath* is a path handled by my resources assembly and *image.png* is some actual png file embedded in that assembly.

If I request this page in a browser, everything works great and the image appears. However, in Visual Studio (at design time) viewing the aspx source shows a compiler warning that "~/virtualpath/image.png" doesn't exist. Viewing in the wysiwyg designer, on the other hand, works and the image appears just as when browsing the page. Seemingly inconsistent, but workable, behavior.

So I also have a master page and its code behind embedded into my resources assembly, but with a slightly different outcome. In my website I can reference the master page with something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/virtualpath/default.master" ...
```

And again, requesting this page in a browser works great and the master page is loaded just as if it were physically a part of the site. But at design time Visual Studio now shows a compile *error*, preventing nice things like code-completion/intellisense when editing the aspx. Worse, the wysiwyg won't load the master page at all and shows an error. (To be honest, I prefer not to work with wysiwygs, but supporting wysiwyg in this particular project is required.)

It appears that Visual Studio only partially supports my VirtualPathProvider at design time. Is this the expected behavior? And if so, is there some way I can configure or otherwise trick Visual Studio into always honoring my VirtualPathProvider when resolving virtual paths at design time?

Comment: Check out these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364129/asp-net-virtualpathprovider-and-visual-studio-intellisense and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284678/problem-with-master-page-and-virtual-path-provider

Comment: Thanks @patmortech, I hadn't seen the second link before. The solutions they propose I've more or less used in the past. Guess I was hoping by framing the question a little different I might get a new answer. VS and Asp.Net must be doing something at design time to understand how to work with resources specified via virtual path ('~'), so I'm asking more generally if there's any facility for controlling that behavior. If there is, adding design time support should be theoretically trivial. And the same would apply to pre-building the site.